Undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
I'm working on an SFML project, but when I try to compile, the main.exe file doesn't get created. I'm using a Makefile, but I keep getting an error:
The error
This is the MakeFile:
all: compile link

compile:
    g++ -Isrc/include -c coding/*.cpp

link:
    g++ *.o -o main -Lsrc/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lopengl32 -lsfml-audio

Make version:
Make version
I tried to fix it by watching some videos, but I couldn't find anything, and honestly, I don't really know what I'm doing. That's why I'm asking for help here.

If you look for that error message (about missing WinMain) you should be getting plenty of hits explaining the issue. If you then refine the search to also include make and gcc and sfml then hopefully you should be able to get enough information how to solve the problem.

Unrelated: this Makefile provides no benefits over a shell script. It will always compile everything sequentially. Learn about the implicit .cpp.o rule in Make so you can at least compile in parallel and only what changed. The link step should then depend on the individual object files so it only relinks if one of them changes.

You're simply missing the main() function, or aren't compiling the file with it. The duplicate is a bit misleading.
